# Can Google CloudSQL report debug logs?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am finding useful information locally in postgres logs using log level debug2. Is it possible to get logs of the same level from CloudSQL?

Comment: how are you setting this log level (at the psql client or via a server parameter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This official [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#list-flags-postgres) shows you can add flags "log_min_messages" and "log_min_error_statement" with value "debug2".